# Warnings with NSString

Tags: twitter, nsstring, warnings, integration, uitextfield

I have the lines

```
usernameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:[username text]];
[username setText:usernameString]; // <--- warning Format not a string literal and no format arguments
```

username is a UITextField

Tell me if you need anymore info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to duplicate the string, you can do that using `initWithString:`, which gives you back a new string with the same contents as the string passed in:

```
usernameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[username text]];
```

Comment: Thanks! I was following an old tutorial and didn't catch that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`usernameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[username text]];`

Don't forget to release `usernameString` later, if you need to.